# Chatroom like Facebook

Tags: facebook

How does Facebook create a real time popout chatroom when somebody like a friend sends you a chat message?

Answer (score 2):

The technique is called **Comet** or **Long Polling**.

See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)) for a good introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at NodeJS, it's much better than long polling.

Also check https://github.com/endtwist/AjaxIM